# mapping non contineous shared memory as contineous for process through character driver mmap()

Tags: c, memory, module, linux-kernel

Being a complete new in kernel module programming, I should extend character driver module for shared memory allocation for processes which is able to map discontinuous memory  to continuous memory in virtual address space of process and also should be able to re-size it.

By resizing i mean kernel module should take care when resizing , for addition/ deletion of pages dynamically ,and new allocated area should be accessed continuously by process which uses shared memory.

Do i need to do remap_pfn_range every time there is re-size request ?

I would really thankful if someone could point to me possible ways of approach...

Comment: Please tag with the target OS for your driver

Comment: I am working on L4Linux to be specific and first want to try the logic on normal Linux character driver kernel module